# python is reading <str> as <float> and it is resulting in errors in my code

Tags: python, pandas

```
str(datecol)
print (type(datecol[0]))
for i in datecol:
    year = i[0:4]

print (year)
```

Hello! I previously asked a question similar to this, but couldn't find any information that helped solved it on the website. My issue is that even after converting each element of my list to string, when I try to run the line `year = i[0:4]` it returns an error saying that float types are not subscriptable. I have printed out the types of each element, and this has confirmed that they are all strings, so this is where my confusion is. I would appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Could you provide the actual error you are getting?

Comment: `str(datecol)` doesn't convert the elements to strings

Comment: Add `print(i, type(i))` to your loop. I'll bet you'll see that they're not all strings.

Comment: Where is pandas being used?

Comment: You have to assign the converted value to your variable : `datecol = str(datecol)`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille thank you! That worked like a charm. Total blonde moment for me